# Test exception raising in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, controller-action

I have a simple controller action which is used for checking that the app is running.

```
def check(id=1)
  Car.find(id)
  render nothing: true, status: 200
rescue
  render nothing: true, status: 500
end
```

How do I test the exception. Below is the test for the happy path.

```
RSpec.describe HealthController do

  describe "GET #check" do
    it "returns 200" do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  end
end
```

Comment: Check for a status of 500? I don't see the issue. However a failed find will already raise a 404, which is more semantically meaningful.

Comment: I appreciate your point. The purpose of the action is to check that the app  and the database are not down. I can ping the controller action regularly and automatically get notified if there are issues with the app. Hence why I capture the exception with a 500 status.

Comment: Unfortunately you capture *every* exception, not just "DB is down" exceptions. If the *app* is down you don't really need to capture an exception... from the app that's down. It's down. Your request will time out.

Comment: Thats fine, thats what I want. I realise you may not see the point of what I'm doing but you haven't really addressed the question.

Comment: Yes, I did. You check for the other status, with the caveat that Rails may raise and render its own exception before your `rescue` block can get executed. Is your question actually how to mock `find`? Same as anything else, and it depends what mocking library you're using, e.g., `Car.stubs(:find).raises(WhateveExceptionYouWant)` with Mocha.

Comment: Thx. I ended up using a before block with allow(Preorder).to receive(:first) {Exception} then get :check and expect(response).to have http_status(200). (sorry for the pseudo code, may help someone else). Also changed my method to just get first record. If you want to create an answer, I'm happy to 'accept' it.

Comment: The exceptional case shouldn't get a 200 back, though, no? If the purpose is to ensure the controller returns an HTTP 500 if the DB is down?

Comment: Oops, copied in the wrong code - alllow(Car).to receive(:first).and_raise(Exception);  get :check; expect(response).to have_http_status(500). Thx for your comments